# Getting Error in Server for dbutil() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to take db backup in codeigniter using function dbutil. It is working fine in local but in live server i am getting some php error. Please help me where i did wrong.

below is my code and error

**Controller**

```
function db_backup()
{
   $this->load->dbutil();

   $prefs = array(     
                    'format'      => 'zip',             
                    'filename'    => 'industry_speak.sql'
                  );

   $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

   $db_name = 'is-backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
   $save = './assets/db_backup/'.$db_name;

   $this->load->helper('file');
   write_file($save, $backup); 

   $this->load->helper('download');

   force_download($db_name, $backup);

}
```

**Error**

In line No. 3775 below code is present.

```
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Runtime Notice
>
> Message: Only variables should be assigned by reference
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 3775
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/acetronsma/public_html/application/controllers/Admin.php
>   Line: 3775 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/acetronsma/public_html/index.php Line: 316 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: Have you tried by removing `&` sign from this line?

Comment: No @RejoanulAlam

Comment: It's working thank you @RejoanulAlam

Answer (score 1):

$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

remove =&,

cm